# CakePHP Facebook Plugin redirection problem

Tags: cakephp, facebook

I have implemented Nick's Facebook Plugin.

Have Imported the Facebook Helper and Connect Component in the app_controller. Changed the Html accordingly.

app_controller.php

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {

    var $components = array('Session', 'Facebook.Connect' => array('createUser' => false), 'Auth');

    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('*');

        $this->set('fbuser',$this->Connect->user());


    }

    function beforeFacebookSave() {
    }

    function beforeFacebookLogin($user) {
        //Logic to happen before a facebook login
    }

    function afterFacebookLogin() {
        //Logic to happen after successful facebook login.
    }

}
?>
```

in the home.ctp

```
<?php
if($fbuser) {
    echo $this->Facebook->logout();
    debug($fbuser);
} else {

    echo $this->Facebook->login();
}
?>
```

Once i click login and allow the permissions. it keeps refreshing indefinitely :(

My App settings online

[image]

Am on Windows Machine and access the code with this base http://localhost/spider/

i also set the canvas url as follows

[image]

I think its because of the configuration on the application settings online. Nick in the Video visits localhost.localdomain/websites/facebook_example to access the code. What is the need of the ".localdomain"

Comment: +1 I had this same problem and posted it on Nick's website, but got no answer.

Comment: @Nick i solved this. this has nothing to do with the code. its to do with the settings on Facebook Developer App Settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I found the answer here:

http://ardentdev.com/no-facebook-connect-cookies-for-localhost-development/

*While doing some Facebook Connect development, I found that the expected cookies were not being set when developing on localhost.  To fix the problem, I added localhost.local to my hosts file (pointing at 127.0.0.1) and changed the settings for my Facebook application to use localhost.local as the base domain.*